# C++ default behavior for arrays - shallow copies?

Tags: c++

As the title says - I need the content of the v array not to change outside of the function.

I thought that it would not happen (because AFAIK the default behavior of arrays is to deep copy - but it looks like it is not).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void testModif(int *v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        v[i]++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int *v;
    v = new int[100];
    *v = 0;
    testModif(v);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

How can I make v not change after running testModif?

Comment: well, you pass a pointer, so it updates the pointed-to array, instead of copying it. and what did you expect? the answer is to use `std::array`, which has proper value semantics instead of readily decaying to a pointer like plain arrays do, so pass that into `testModif` by value and it'll update its own local copy instead of the original one.

Comment: *How can I make v not change after running testModif?* Use `std::array` or `std::vector`, they support deep copies.

Comment: If you use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of C-style arrays, that will give you the option to use either value or reference semantics to choose whether or not the array should be copied.

Comment: Another good reason to instead use `std::array` is you might forget to `delete[] v`. Oh wait, you did forget.

Comment: In `void testModif(int *v)` does `v` look like an array to you? You cannot have an array as a parameter to a function in C++, so the issue of deep copies or shallow copies is irrelevant.

Comment: well for 100 `int`s it doesn't even need `new`

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing `int *v; v = new int[100];` to `int *v = new int[100];`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can enlist the compilers help by declaring as

```
void testModif(const int *v);
```

I.e. as `v` being a non-const pointer to `const int`.  I.e. you can e.g. increment the copy of the pointer, but not change what the pointer points to.

With that change the shown code will get errors/warnings, which at least tell you that you are doing what you do not want to do.

Then you need to change your code to follow your self-decided rule.
For the shown code that would require making a copy of the array itself (not only of the pointer pointing to it). Exactly, that would match "deep copy" in contrast to the "shallow copy" you mention.

Most closely to your shown code would be a local copy, an array of size 5 (magic number, but you know what I mean) or something malloced of proper size (and of course freed before leaving the function).

Obviously making a local copy, incrementing all members and then leaving the function again normally would seem pointless. I trust that this is purely to be blamed to you making an appropriate MRE. I.e. the point that intentionally not changing the original values and only locally incrementing is what you want to achieve.

Of course I am not contradicting the comments to your question, which recommend the more C++ way of doing things, with standard containers, like `std::array`, `std::vector`.

Comment: Yes, that was because I wanted to make an appropiate MRE. WHat I understand from your post is that I have to create another array to hold the initial values. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, exactly. (Though I would not describe the copied values as "initial" values, surely not after you changed them. If you allow nitpicking I would describe them as "copies of original values"). For making a C-like array you need to know the size, which seems to be 5. If there is no constant magic number, things like this usually are done with a second parameter to the function, giving the size. And do not worry, when I wrote "appropriate MRE", I really meant there is nothing wrong with it. (I just had to defend my answer against not unreasonable "but that is meaningless code" criticisms.)

Comment: Okay. Got you. Thanks for your time :)